# Using createAttribute vs. just setting the attribute directly?

Tags: javascript

In javascript, we can create a new DOM element in the following ways...

By using the createAttribute() + setAttributeNode() dom methods:

```
var input = document.createElement("input"),
    type = document.createAttribute("type");

type.nodeValue = "text";
input.setAttributeNode(type);
container.appendChild(input);
```

or by just setting the attributes directly:

```
var input = document.createElement("input");

input.type = "text";
container.appendChild(input);
```

The latter can end up being quite lot less code, even when there are only a couple attributes per element.

*The question*: has anyone run across any drawbacks of the latter method (setting attributes directly)?

I tested this on several browsers (the latest FF, IE, Safari, Opera, old IEs - even IE6 worked) and on a basic test (inserting a text input with type, name, and maxLength attributes) they all passed.  [Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DonamiteIsTNT/GG7tF/6/embedded/result/) if anybody needs it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
document.createAttribute
document.createAttributeNS
element.getAttributeNode
element.getAttributeNodeNS
... and a lot of others
```

will be deprecated in DOM4, so don't use it, just set with setAttribute("name","value")

http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#element

someinput.type is different
basically is a shortcut for doing

```
setAttribute("type","text");
getAttribute("text");
```

hope this helps!

```
element._some_attribute_ is not available for all attributes, just some:
element.dir
element.lang
element.id
...etc
```

Comment: It's not entirely true that using `setAttribute()` and `getAttribute()` is always equivalent to using the corresponding property. For example, the `value` property (which always reflects the current value of an input) exists separately from the `value` attribute (which represents only the initial value). A more obvious example is the `style` attribute, which contains a string, versus the `style` property, which is a `CSSStyleDeclaration` object with individual properties for each individual style property.

Comment: where did i say that they're always equivalent? :P

Comment: Fair point, you didn't. Not sure what prompted my comment now.

Comment: @TimDown nonetheless, appreciate the indepth distinction

Comment: See you in a couple of years for my next comment :)

Answer (score 3):

Apparantly IE 5.5 has issues with using the attribute name (i.e. `node[attributeName]`). [Quirksmode has this well documented](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html).