# create attribute in js triggers an exception 'not a function'

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, scratchpad

I'm using js to change the contents of a div that contents inputs i want to use them with Ajax ,
I've used Firefox scratchpad to debug this function:

```
function show(id){
var div = document.getElementById('com');
div.innerHTML = '';
var input1 = document.createElement('input')
            .createAttribute('type').setAttribute('type', 'hidden')
            .createAttribute('value').setAttribute('value',id )
            .setAttribute('name','id' );
var input2 = document.createElement('input')
             .createAttribute('type').setAttribute('type', 'input')
             .createAttribute('name').setAttribute('name', 'com');
var btn = document.createElement('button')
          .createAttribute('onClick').setAttribute('onClick', 'post()');
btn.innerHTML = 'Comment';
div.appendChild(input1).appendChild(input2).appendChild(btn);
}
```

and what i got is this:

```
/*
Exception: document.createElement(...).createAttribute is not a function
@Scratchpad/2:2
*/
```

I understood nothing, any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe `.createAttribute()` belongs to `document`, not to individual elements, so that would explain that error: `.createElement()` returns an element, and that element has no function `.createAttribute()`.

But you don't need to use `.createAttribute()` before calling `.setAttribute()`, because the latter will create element attributes if they don't already exist. However, I think `.setAttribute()` returns `undefined` so you can't really chain it. Try doing it one step at a time:

```
var input1 = document.createElement('input');
input1.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
input1.setAttribute('value',id );
input1.setAttribute('name','id' );
// etc.
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically, the exception says that there is no function called "createAttribute". And that is correct:

`.createAttribute()` is a function of `document`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document#Methods

So the functions cannot be chained like you try to do it. You have to call them individually. And anyway, "createAttribute" should not be used anymore (see [Using createAttribute vs. just setting the attribute directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677930/using-createattribute-vs-just-setting-the-attribute-directly)).

```js
function show(id){
    var div = document.getElementById('com');
    div.innerHTML = '';

    var input1 = document.createElement('input');
    input1.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    input1.setAttribute('value',id );
    input1.setAttribute('name','id' );

    var input2 = document.createElement('input');
    input2.setAttribute('type', 'input');
    input2.setAttribute('name', 'com');

    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.setAttribute('onClick', 'post()');
    btn.innerHTML = 'Comment';

    div.appendChild(input1).appendChild(input2).appendChild(btn);
}
```