# Directly add an attribute as an element property

Tags: javascript, html

Here's how I change the value of an existing attribute:

```
element.attributeName = "value"
```

But is it OK to use the above method to create a *new* attribute?

Notes:

1. JavaScript only.
2. Please provide the relevant documentation.
3. I don't need to support old browsers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677930/using-createattribute-vs-just-setting-the-attribute-directly

Comment: I'm already aware of `Element.setAttribute`. Please read my question again.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `setAttribute`. I just wonder if the above method is OK or not.

Comment: This question is perfectly valid. It's not a matter of preference or opinion, the question raises a question whether it's valid code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`element.attribute = x` works for W3C defined attributes or already specified node attributes on your element.

This is the exact working as it reads on MDN:

```
if attributeName is a W3C defined attribute and an attribute node for the element (e.g., id),
that Attribute Node gets assigned the value of x

if attributeName isn't a W3C defined attribute or an attribute node for the element, 
the element's (JavaScript object) attributeName property is assigned the value of x
```

See *Syntax* section on this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.attributes

**Examples**

Take below DOM element

```
<div data-goals="3" id="container"></div>
```

You would be fine modifying `data-goals` through

```
document.getElementById('container').dataGoals = '4';
```

You are also able to add new attributes, if these are defined by W3C, e.g. `title`

```
document.getElementById('container').title = 'This is a title';
```

But you should not expect to be able to set a new attribute which is not defined by W3C

```
document.getElementById('container').myOwnAttribute = 'something';
```

Comment: Something important to note: some attributes have different DOM names than attribute names, for example `class` is `className` or `value` is `defaultValue`.

Answer (score -2):

Here is your answer: [add new attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949645/creating-a-new-attribute-with-jquery)

**EDITED:**

pure JavaScript:

[1st](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710275/how-to-add-update-an-attribute-to-an-html-element-using-javascript)
[2nd](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/setAttribute)

Comment: As I said `JavaScript` only.